# Is it possible to find $P$ for $P \begin{pmatrix} a & d\\ b & e \\c & f \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} xa & yd\\ xb & ye \\xc & yf\end{pmatrix}$?

Tags: matrices

I am trying to solve the following matrix equation.

$$P \begin{pmatrix} a & d\\ b & e \\c & f \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} xa & yd\\ xb & ye \\xc & yf\end{pmatrix}$$

I know that $P$ must be $3 \text { by } 3$ matrix.

## Question

Is $P$ solvable? I have tried but it seems to be impossible. Is there any theorem to know whether or not a matrix equation has a solution?

Comment: There is a solution with $P$ a $2×2$ matrix on the right of the $3×2$ matrix, instead of a $3×3$ matrix on the left.

Comment: @Empy2: Yes. You are right. I did it before.

Comment: Are there any special equations you know about $a,b,c,d,e,f,x,y$?

Comment: @LegNaiB: No. For arbitrary.

Comment: Only if $x=y$, for otherwise arbitrary ${a..f}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote the vectors (in the standard basis)

$$u =\begin{pmatrix} a\\ b\\ c\end{pmatrix} \text{ and } v= \begin{pmatrix} d\\ e\\ f\end{pmatrix}.$$ The equation

$$P \begin{pmatrix} a & d\\ b & e \\c & f \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} xa & yd\\ xb & ye \\xc & yf\end{pmatrix}$$ is equivalent to the two equations $P.u = xu, P.v = yv$. Which means if $u \neq 0$ that $u$ is an eigenvector of $P$ associated to the eigenvalue $x$; similar consideration for $v$ and $y$.

Suppose that $u,v$ are linearly independent and complete with $w$ to obtain a basis $\mathcal B = \{u,v,w\}$. Now define $Q$ by the matrix (in the canonical basis)

$$Q = \begin{pmatrix} x & 0 & 0\\
0 & y & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

Finally, if $T$ is the matrix to pass from the basis $\mathcal B$ to the canonical basis, the matrix $P = T^{-1}QT$ is a solution to the problem as

$$P.u = (T^{-1}QT).u= (T^{-1}Q)(T.u)=(T^{-1}Q).e_1=T^{-1}.(x e_1)=xu$$ and similarly for $v$.

A (very) simple example:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \\0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 2 \\0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

Notes:

1. You can in fact chose whatever you want for the last column of $Q$.
2. If $u,v$ are non zero but linearly dependent, you need to have $x=y$.

Comment: Rigorously explained answer won! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Consider swapping the columns of the (right) multiplicand,

$$\begin{align*}
P\begin{pmatrix}a&d\\b&e\\c&f\end{pmatrix}
&= P\begin{pmatrix}d&a\\e&b\\f&c\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\\
&= \begin{pmatrix}xd&ya\\xe&yb\\xf&yc\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\\
&= \begin{pmatrix}ya&xd\\yb&xe\\yc&xf\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}$$

This forces that $x=y$.

Comment: This is wrong as $P\begin{pmatrix}d&a\\e&b\\f&c\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}yd&xa\\ye&xb\\yf&xc\end{pmatrix}$ and not $P\begin{pmatrix}d&a\\e&b\\f&c\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}xd&ya\\xe&yb\\xf&yc\end{pmatrix} $.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net The question says $a$ to $f$ are arbitrary, so according to the requirement equation and by renaming the inputs, $$P\begin{pmatrix}d&a\\e&b\\f&c\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}xd&ya\\xe&yb\\xf&yc\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Arbitrary, but fixed for the problem.